# Why does the English translation of Lorem Ipsum text yield proper output in IBM Watson Personality Insights, when it should be flagged as an error?

Tags: ibm-watson, personality-insights

Screenshot of input text as English translation of Lorem Ipsum placeholder text with summary output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing all the text or the exact response, it looks like the reason is that there are enough English words that it finds in that text to hit the threshold to return a response (100 words). Just the in the screen shot I see about 32 English words (even if the sentence doesn't quite make sense).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!